# Show all the clients connected to a socket server and send them data

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, sockets, server

I have this simple code:

```
import socket

socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket.bind((host, port))
socket.listen()
while True:
    client_socket, addr = socket.accept()
    send = input("Send: ") # but I need a way to send it to all the clients connected
    if send == "devices":
    # here I'd have a list of all devices connected
    client_socket.send(send.encode())
    data = client_socket.recv(4096)
    print (data)
```

As I wrote in the comments, I need a way to manage them all in one. How can I do? Maybe with _thread library?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand where your trouble is. If you need to keep track of all connected clients then do that, add the client_socket to a python list after `socket.accept()`. Are you perhaps a python beginner?

Comment: @sperly1987 Did you ever figure out a good solution to this? I need to solve this as well - looking into using connection pooling. I appreciate any direction you can provide!

Answer (score 1):

You could mainitain a list of clients that can be passed to an external function that performs an action on all clients.

```
import socket

host = ''
port = 1000
max_connections = 5


socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket.bind((host, port))
socket.listen(max_connections)
clients = []    # Maintain a list of clients
try:
    while True:
        client_socket, addr = socket.accept()
        clients.append(client_socket)    #Add client to list on connection
        i_manage_clients(clients)       #Call external function whenever necessary
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    socket.close()

def i_manage_clients(clients):    #Function to manage clients
    for client in clients:
        client.send('Message to pass')
```

The above example demonstrates how send data to all clients at once. You could use the

```
import socket
from thread import *

host = ''
port = 1000
max_connections = 5


socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket.bind((host, port))
socket.listen(max_connections)
try:
    while True:
        client_socket, addr = socket.accept()
        start_new_thread(i_manage_client, (client_socket,addr))
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    socket.close()

def i_manage_client(client_socket, addr):    #Function to manage clients
    client_socket.send('Message to pass')
    data = client_socket.recv(4096)
    print(client_socket)
    print(addr)
    print(data)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I noticed that there are some mistakes in you code, for example the while flag cycle... what's flag? I replaced it with while True... you also called a function in while flag cycle (i_manage_clients) before declaring it. and in the end yu can't send "Lol" without encoding it so I had to use .encode() function. but, even if I corrected these errors, it doesn't work with broken pipe error or connection reset by peer :\

Comment: @AllExJ: This is an example, not necessarily something to cut&paste verbatim into your code. It shows two concepts you claimed to need: 1) saving connected clients in a list, and 2) iterating over the list of connected clients to send a message to each one.

Comment: Sorry for the error caused by the flag variable. I have edited the code and also added the usage of threading that was required.

Comment: thanks Trishant, but it isn't what I'm looking for :\

Comment: Could try again if you could specify it a bit more?